# update current_user on sign in of rails 4 app

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been tearing my hair out over the last couple of days with a problem that happens only on my heroku server and not locally on my machine. Hopefully someone will have the answer.

In my app I'm using the signin method outlined by Michael Hartl's [rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#cha-sign_in_sign_out). I'm having a problem on signin when I'm trying to set current user, current_user isn't being set after the redirect to the users home page. This is the create action in the session_controller.rb:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        puts "Current user in the session controller? #{current_user}"
        redirect_back_or user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end 
end
```

The signin method in sessions_helper.rb:

```
def sign_in user
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))

    self.current_user = user
end
```

The current_user getters and setters:

```
def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

The redirect_back_or method (also in sessions_helper.rb):

```
def redirect_back_or default
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

All this is in the tutorial. It works fine on local host but on heroku I get an error because current user is not set on the user page when it gets redirected there. The heroku logs are this:

```
2014-05-02T19:10:50.217046+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 109.154.60.142 at 2014-05-02 19:10:50 +0000
2014-05-02T19:10:50.225878+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-05-02T19:10:50.225988+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"d5XNCy1PGsu/DZM8NUM+OrSzVYUqthlzzwv/ma3ub6U=", "session"=>{"email"=>"brownie3003@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign-in"}
2014-05-02T19:10:50.405719+00:00 app[web.1]: Current user in the session controller? #<User:0x007f7355f16308>
2014-05-02T19:10:50.409758+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 183ms
2014-05-02T19:10:50.409397+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.pocket-social.com/users/brownie3003
2014-05-02T19:10:50.890513+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"brownie3003"}
2014-05-02T19:10:50.911543+00:00 app[web.1]: Current User is set to:
2014-05-02T19:10:50.890503+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
2014-05-02T19:10:50.883835+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/brownie3003" for 109.154.60.142 at 2014-05-02 19:10:50 +0000
2014-05-02T19:10:51.194600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/brownie3003 host=www.pocket-social.com request_id=fcb944a1-5fbf-4100-bc62-6e692b3fa29f fwd="109.154.60.142" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=316ms status=500 bytes=1530
2014-05-02T19:10:51.185308+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms
2014-05-02T19:10:51.185064+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/show.html.slim within layouts/application (49.8ms)
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187641+00:00 app[web.1]:      5: - unless current_user == @user
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187646+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:     - elsif current_user.pocket.nil?
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187642+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:     - if @user.pocket == nil
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187648+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:         h3 You need to connect your pocket before you can see what other people have in their pocket.
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187650+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:         p = button_to "Associate Pocket Account", new_pocket_path , css: "btn btn-primary", method: 'get'
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187652+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:         p
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187654+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/show.html.slim:8:in `_app_views_users_show_html_slim___15552049447878886_70066683727980'
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187656+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187644+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:         p Sorry this user has not associated their pocket account yet so you can't subscribe to them.
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187635+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187639+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pocket' for nil:NilClass):
2014-05-02T19:10:51.187657+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-02T19:10:51.545623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.pocket-social.com request_id=391fdab8-6556-4c2b-87dd-7d091ade9680 fwd="109.154.60.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=111
```

I can see when the GET '/users/brownie3003' is performed the the current_user variable is not set (I call puts "Current User is set to: #{current_user}").

I've been tearing my hair out, if anyone could help that would be amazing. Let me know if you need me to post any more info.

Comment: you sure your error hasnt got something to do with ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pocket' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: Hey @Richlewis, I've updated the heroku logs because I think I missed a bit off. It seems to me that the error of undefined method 'pocket' for nil:NilClass is because I'm trying to apply my pocket method to current_user when it's nil. I'm pretty sure @ user will not be nil.